# Using alarms with the DS1307RTC

Tags: arduino, rtc

I'm trying to wrap my head around following library:
http://rweather.github.com/arduinolibs/classDS1307RTC.html

I can see that the DS1307RTC has a writeAlarm and readAlarm function. 
I'm not sure how I should use these functions, do I need to manually check if the alarm has passed in my loop function? 
Or should I use this in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at [DS1307 datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1307.pdf) it seems that it doesn't support an alarm. Some other RTCs have alarm interrupt output that alerts the controller.

I believe that you would have to deal with alarm in the software. You would have to check for alarm condition by comparing the current time with the alarm variable in software.

Another option is to look at [DS1337](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1337-DS1337C.pdf) that has alarm functionality:
[image: ref design]
[image: features]